# Finding matrix modulo n inverse in octave

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, octave, modulo

I have to find the modulo 29 inverse of a 30x30 matrix. I've tried using the det^-1 * adjoint, but I can't seem to find the det^-1 because the det is something like -7.4269e+16. Any ideas?

Comment: The matrix is (near) singular. Also see discussion: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326063/inverse-of-a-matrix-mod-26
You can also try: http://planetcalc.com/3324/ - it should give the answer, or tell you it is singular.

Comment: A large determinant hints towards a large condition number, which is meaningless for the purpose of modular computations. In this case, the matrix is only singular if the determinant is an integer multiple of 29.

Comment: What is the matrix in question? I think one can use [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net) to find the modular inverse. Maxima will use exact arithmetic so the condition number has no effect. Maxima doesn't seem to have a built-in function for the modular inverse, but its function `linsolve` will solve equations with modular arithmetic, so one could do it with a little extra work. I can help with that if you want to go down that road.

Comment: Do you have to use Octave? It sounds like the wrong tool for this job.  SAGE or PARI/GP would do this with ease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the computation of modular powers, it is advisable and even essential for an efficient implementation to reduce the intermediate results modulo 29.

Thus if there is no dedicated algorithm for this function or modular integer number type usable in the standard function calls in matlab, you will have to implement a variant of the Gauß-algorithm on your own.

---

Using google one of course finds solutions for everything: [modsolve.m](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22725-variable-precision-integer-arithmetic/content/VariablePrecisionIntegers/modsolve.m)